# Getting output from remote hudson builds

Tags: jenkins, plugins, hudson

I have recently added several Hudson agent machines to a working controller.

Some of the builds have result files (Doxygen output, Boost unit test results, cppcheck) which are published using the relevant plugins.

If these builds run on the controller, the output files are published successfully, but if they run on an agent, the build fails because the files cannot be found.

The plugins seem to be looking for the output files on the controller, when of course, they are on the agent.

Is there a way to fix this?

```
Plugins used:
 - Jenkins Cppcheck Plug-in V1.2
 - Doxygen Plugin V0.9
 - HTML Publisher plugin V0.6
```

Edit:
Tried archiving suggestion, but I can't get it to work.  cppcheck.xml is archived correctly and exists in the relative directory ../lastSuccessful/archive/cppcheck.xml

Hudson log:

```
Archiving artifacts
[Cppcheck] Starting the cppcheck analysis.
[Cppcheck] No cppcheck test report file(s) were found with the pattern
    '../lastSuccessful/archive/cppcheck.xml' relative to
    '/home/hudson/.hudson/jobs/1.11-IntegrationDebug/workspace'.  
    Did you enter a pattern relative to the correct directory?  
    Did you generate the XML report(s) for Cppcheck?
[Cppcheck] Parsing throws exceptions. No cppcheck test report file(s) were 
    found with the pattern '../lastSuccessful/archive/cppcheck.xml' relative to 
    '/home/hudson/.hudson/jobs/1.11-IntegrationDebug/workspace'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: copy artifacts into your workspace and publish from there.

Comment: There is a bug opened for HTML Publisher plugin: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-6780. However, it seems that the maintaner claims that it should work.